# Girlfriend in the US, boyfriend (me) in South Africa

Tags: us-citizens, family, marriage, south-african-citizens

My girlfriend is in America (Kansas). I can't find any good information. I know US citizens don't need visas to visit South Africa (good news for us), but I need one to go there. I have no money, no job, I'm basically homeless.

What I want to know is, can she visit me for the 90 days and can she do that constantly? How long can she stay with me? How and what can we do to stay together?

Or, how can I get to America to live there? I know you need to show you can support yourself while staying there (I can't) and you need to find a job before going there. What other options do we have? (Even marriage, that will come!)

Also my mom, dad and I want to go to America. We want to get out of here. How can we get there? We are basically dead down. we can't find a job. We live at our old work, which closed down after the boss committed suicide. So we are stuck. Market is down after a company near us dismissed around 32K people.

I'm also willing to talk on Discord, or by email.

Comment: Enter the green card lottery, and hope.  Getting employer sponsorship for a work visa would be another option if your skills are sufficient.

Comment: For more information about green card lottery https://www.uscis.gov/greencard/diversity-visa be careful as there are similar scam websites

Comment: thatts the main problem. im not really that smart oe exeptional. nor do i have qualifications. nor do i have money. but i do have my gf there that i can marry so. i idk what do do anymore here.

Comment: @ruangoofy if you're still around, your future wife would be able to sponsor you for immigration after you marry.  For you to sponsor your parents, you must first naturalize as a US citizen, which requires three years of residence in the US, and then if the petition is approved they would have to wait for visas to become available (they would be in a category that is subject to an annual numerical limit).